# Dynamically Adjusting Lightning-Input-Rich-Text's textarea

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, salesforce-communities

Im trying to increase the height of the textarea box after a user creates several line breaks within the textarea. I'm having issues finding a way to target the value of the textarea height in order to increase it per line break. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TextBoxSizing extends LightningElement {
    handleTextBoxChange(event){
        let eventArr = [];
        let lineBreaks = 0;
    
        eventArr.push(...event.target.value); 
        eventArr.forEach(e =>{
          if(e == '/'){
          lineBreaks++;
          if(lineBreaks > 5) {

          let lirt = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-rich-text').height; //undefined 
          console.log(lirt); 
 
          } 
         }
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/)? Read the article, read the documentation for [textarea](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/textarea/#Styling-Hooks-Overview), check if adding `TextBoxSizing.css` with something like

```
:host {
    --sds-c-textarea-sizing-min-height: 10em;
}
```

works OK.

If it does - next step would be to add a JavaScript-controlled variable to CSS. I had similar question a while ago: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/341324/799

Something like this?

[image]

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-input-rich-text value={text}></lightning-input-rich-text>

        <lightning-input type="number" label="Wheee :)" value={lines} onchange={handleLines} min="1" max="99"
            variant="label-inline">
        </lightning-input>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class StackTextarea extends LightningElement {

    text = '<b>Hello!</b>';
    lines = 1;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.resize();
    }

    handleLines(event) {
        this.lines = event.target.value;
        this.resize();
    }

    resize() {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--rtf-size', (this.lines * 2) + 'em');
    }
}
```

```css
:host{
    --sds-c-textarea-sizing-min-height: var(--rtf-size);
}
```

Comment: For rich text it's probably https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/rich-text-editor/#Styling-Hooks-Overview but same idea applies

Comment: Im actually am using styling hooks. My problem is coming from trying to target 
":host {
    --sds-c-textarea-sizing-min-height: 10em;
}"

within the js to change it dynamically.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're after, when I played with RTF the field seemed to auto grow as I was pressing Enter key anyway. But this should give you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs it, I went for the following

[100% Rich Text Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc2En.gif)

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class inputRichTextFSC_LWC extends LightningElement {
    
    //Handle updates to Rich Text field with enhanced features
    handleTextChange(event) {

    }

}
```

```css
:host {
    --slds-c-textarea-sizing-min-height: 100%;
    --slds-c-textarea-sizing-max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <lightning-input-rich-text onchange={handleTextChange}>
    </lightning-input-rich-text>
  </div>
</template>
```